# replacing null values in column rows with data for sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

> So i have this example of a nested sub query below which finds nulls for user name id on left join of table 1 to table 2. where i am trying to bring in the following from. the issues in in table 2, some of the data is missing which is where the nulls are coming from. therefor, i am doing sort of a vlookup for the latest person # data and bringing those Username ids.

my nested query to do this is the following:

```
(SELECT MX.USERNAME_ID as [MAX Username]
,MX.[GL_ENTITY_CD]
,MX.GL_ENTITY_DESC
,t.*
FROM (
SELECT 
    [Month]
    ,[Year]
    ,Convert(DATE, [Month] + ' ' + str([Year])) AS [Month date]
    ,[PERSON#]
    ,c.[USERNAME_ID] AS [NDW-Username NULL]
    ,c.[GL_ENTITY_CD] AS [NDW-GL Entity]
    ,c.[GL_ENTITY_DESC] AS [NDW-GL Entity Desc]
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[Table 1]
LEFT JOIN [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE 2] c ON [Year] = c.[yr]
    AND [Month] = c.[MTH]
    AND [PERSON#] = c.[PERSON#_NUM]
) AS t
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT (Convert(DATE, A.[mth] + ' ' + str(A.[yr]))) AS [Max date]
    ,a.*
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE 2] a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT B.[PERSON#_NUM]
            ,max(Convert(DATE, B.[mth] + ' ' + str(B.[yr]))) AS [max date]
        FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE 2] B
        WHERE A.[PERSON#_NUM] = B.[PERSON#_NUM]
        GROUP BY B.[PERSON#_NUM]
        HAVING (Convert(DATE, A.[mth] + ' ' + str(A.[yr]))) = max(Convert(DATE, B.[mth] + ' ' + str(B.[yr])))
        )
) AS MX ON T.[PERSON#] = MX.[PERSON#_NUM]

WHERE t.[NDW-Username NULL] IS NULL
 )
```

Now i finally want to use this query that filled the nulls to fill my actually query data below for anything that is null in the fields below for what i found in the nested query above.

> `c.[USERNAME_ID],c.[GL_ENTITY_CD],c.[GL_ENTITY_DESC]`

my main query this will be going into is:

```
SELECT EF.[Company]
        ,EF.[Month]
        ,EF.[Year]
        ,Convert(DATE, EF.[Month] + ' ' + str(EF.[Year])) AS [Month date]
        ,c.[USERNAME_ID]
        ,c.[GL_ENTITY_CD] AS [NDW-GL Entity]
        ,c.[GL_ENTITY_DESC] AS [NDW-GL Entity Desc]
    FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[Table 1] EF
    LEFT JOIN [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE 2] c ON EF.[Year] = c.[yr]
        AND EF.[Month] = c.[MTH]
        AND EF.[PERSON#] = c.[PERSON#_NUM]
```

the result i want is for data missing for each record in:

> c.[USERNAME_ID],c.[GL_ENTITY_CD],c.[GL_ENTITY_DESC]
> null, null, null

replace with the latest [USERNAME_ID] we have.

i just cant figure out how i can combine the data in [USERNAME_ID] field with existing data and the new nested data for nulls. as i can get the max username_id to show in a separate column but not the same.

Comment: You've tagged MySQL and T-SQL (the dialect for SQL Server) here, and the above is T-SQL. What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: sorry edited. i am using sql server 2012

Comment: `null` is not a value. It denotes a *missing value*.

Comment: To make you question clearer, please edit your queries to drastically reduce the number of columns down to the minimum possible to show the problem (ie maybe 3 or 4). See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Let's make it easier to help you: you should remove any columns not immediately relevant to your question, so the code is smaller and easier to deal with, then add some sample ```Table 1``` and ```Table 2``` data so we can see the issue, and test a resolution.

Comment: @TheImpaler that's up for debate, I would say `NULL` *is* a value, just an unknown one.

Comment: i have removed most fields not relevant for the query above. does this help?